# Error when using Type converters with dagger hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

I am new to dependency injection and currently using dagger-hilt. I had to use type converter in order to insert a list inside an entity.

At run time I am facing a crash because the converter is missing in the database configuration although I am adding it.

Below is my code regarding the type converter, databse class and App Module

```
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class BundleConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromPackageBundleList(countryLang: List<PackageBundle?>?): String? {
        if (countryLang == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<PackageBundle?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(countryLang, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toPackageBundleList(countryLangString: String?): List<PackageBundle>? {
        if (countryLangString == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<PackageBundle?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson<List<PackageBundle>>(countryLangString, type)
    }
}
```

```
@Database(
    entities = [Service::class,SoundEffect::class],
    version = 3,
    exportSchema = false
)
@TypeConverters(BundleConverter::class)
abstract class UserDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getYourDao(): UserDao
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideYourDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext app: Context
    ) = Room.databaseBuilder(
        app,
        UserDatabase::class.java,
        "your_db_name"
    )
        .addTypeConverter(BundleConverter::class)
        .build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideYourDao(db: UserDatabase) = db.getYourDao()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove optional value handling from your database converter class:

```
class BundleConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromPackageBundleList(countryLang: List<PackageBundle>): String =
        return Gson().toJson(countryLang)

    @TypeConverter
    fun toPackageBundleList(countryLangString: String): List<PackageBundle> {
        val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<PackageBundle>>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(countryLangString, type)
    }
}
```